# C# WINFORM ,CONTROLS RESIZING AND LOADING PROBLEM

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have built a new app with some basic Controls like Ribbon as Parent and Other pages as Childs
but I am facing Forms Slow loading and sizing issue as you can see in GIF .
Every time I open this form its Controls resized 3 to 4 time.
Any solution please ????? :( .

[image]

Comment: You should provide more information about form initialize/load

Comment: Still I dId nothing in Coding .its Designing issue .yet no coding started .

Comment: Can you write `this.DoubleBuffered = true;`  on click event of the Button (on Ribbon), or may be on page load of the usercontrol?

Answer (score -1):

I got Solution .

Every time I clicked ,Parent form generate a new form and previous one is still there and not closed so so many same forms are opened at a time .

I try this solution ,

```
    private void btnCompanysetup_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Form frm = new frmCompanySetup();

        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmCompanySetup>().Count() == 1) {


            frm.BringToFront();
        
        }
        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmCompanySetup>().Count() == 0)
        {


            frm.MdiParent = this;
            frm.Show();

        }
          

         
    }
```

Thanks for all those response .